# Flask to Google Cloud Server 500 Error - OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, plotly-dash, spotipy

**Updating Based on Comment Requests (Full Error and Port Reference)**

I'm trying to deploy my Flask app to Google Cloud but keep running into a 500 Server Error (although sometimes it's 502 Bad Gateway). The Flask app runs fine locally, and the gcloud logs show the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py", line 92, in init_process
    super().init_process()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/srv/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from spotiparty import server
  File "/srv/spotiparty.py", line 1395, in <module>
    app.run_server(debug=False, port=8085)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_dash/jupyter_app.py", line 180, in run_server
    super_run_server(**kwargs)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dash/dash.py", line 1750, in run_server
    self.server.run(host=host, port=port, debug=debug, **flask_run_options)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 990, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 1008, in run_simple
    inner()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 957, in inner
    fd=fd,
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 781, in make_server
    host, port, app, request_handler, passthrough_errors, ssl_context, fd=fd
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 686, in __init__
    super().__init__(server_address, handler)  # type: ignore
  File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 452, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/http/server.py", line 137, in server_bind
    socketserver.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 466, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

I've tried troubleshooting with all the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50177696/flask-google-cloud-app-engine-oserror-errno-98-address-already-in-use/50177865), but still keep running into the same error. For some background, the app is using the Spotify API and is initially supposed to prompt the user for their Spotify login. Here is the full code I'm using in **main.py**:

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, g, render_template, session
from spotify_requests import spotify
from spotiparty import server

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'some key for session'

# ----------------------- AUTH API PROCEDURE -------------------------

@app.route("/auth")
def auth():
    return redirect(spotify.AUTH_URL)


@app.route("/callback/")
def callback():

    auth_token = request.args['code']
    auth_header = spotify.authorize(auth_token)
    session['auth_header'] = auth_header

    return profile()

def valid_token(resp):
    return resp is not None and not 'error' in resp

# -------------------------- API REQUESTS ----------------------------

@app.route("/")
def index():
    src = server
    return render_template('index.html', src=src)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=False, port=spotify.PORT)
```

**spotify.py** contains the API credentials and **spotiparty.py** contains the bulk of my application being deployed, including a separate Dash/Flask framework that is being linked to the server in main. The **spotify.PORT** reference within the app run at the bottom of my code simply points to a variable in **spotify.py** which stores the value 8080 (have also tried with various other port values to make sure it's not running on the same server as gcloud).

Based on the suggestions in the linked post above, I've tried commenting out the **if **name** == "**main**"** block, switching the app run to a different port, and setting the Flask port directly from the command line, but I still receive the same error and logs in gcloud on every run.

I feel like I've hit a bit of a wall on this one, but given that the app runs fine locally I think I must be close to getting it up and running (maybe wishful thinking). Any help here would be greatly appreciated, and please let me know if there's any other info I can provide on the other scripts involved in the app or the gcloud logs resulting from the server errors.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: Where are you deploying your app? On Compute Engine?